# FTP/SFTP Server thats scriptable

Tags: ftp, sftp, net-sftp

I am looking for a windows FTP/SFTP server software that I can administrate (partly) by scripting against it, or if it has a .NET or COM API but at the end of the day I need to execute scripts/tasks against it that adds accounts and such.

I have considered building my own c# implementation but it seems unneccecary to do that by my self when there probably are tons of great ftp and sftp software out there.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

/Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html) is a lightweight and fast Windows FTP/FTPS/SFTP/SCP server. At times we've considered adding the ability to do various admin things via a script. If you [contact us](http://www.enterprisedt.com/contact.html) and let us know what your requirements are, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`solt_sftp`](https://github.com/aek/solt_sftp), that is a SFTP server developed in Python based on `Paramiko` and running under Gevent greenlets. Users can be managed in `Redis` and there is a Redis channel to notify the SFTP server for user add/modify dynamically.